# limitar un registro agrupado de mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una consulta mysql que lo que hace es agrupar los registros por id_canal y dentro de ese grupo concatenar sus filas en un option:

```
$query = "SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT('<option value=\"',pl.id_lote,'\">',DATE(pl.fecha),'  |  ',pl.unidades,' uni. |  S/ ',pl.precio_costo,'</option>' SEPARATOR '') AS options,c.canal
from productos_lotes pl
left join canales c on c.id_canal = pl.id_canal
where pl.id_producto = ".$id."
group by pl.id_canal
ORDER BY fecha
";

$canales = $bd->query($query)->fetch_all();
foreach ($canales as $keyy1) {$options_result .= "<optgroup label='".$keyy1[1]."'>".$keyy1[0]."</optgroup>";}
```

esto lo hago para optener esto:

```
<optgroup label='Nombre del canal 1'>
<option>Id del lote</option>
<option>Id del lote</option>
<option>Id del lote</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label='Nombre del canal 2'>
<option>Id del lote</option>
<option>Id del lote</option>
<option>Id del lote</option>
</optgroup>
```

de momento todo bien, el codigo funciona y tal; la cosa es que yo quiero limitar el numero de filas a concatenar, es decir solo quiero mostrar los 10 ultimos registros ordenados por `pl.fecha` ;

yo intente ponerle un limit 10 pero lo que hace es solo mostrarme los todos los registros de los primeros 10 canales.

espero me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: Prueba agregando esto: `ORDER BY pl.fecha DESC`, así te ordenará por fecha en forma descendente, es decir, de la mayor fecha a la menor.

Comment: Tienes que modificar tu consulta principal añadiendo al final `ORDER BY pl.fecha DESC LIMIT 10` De esta forma te aseguras de obtener **los 10 ultimos registros ordenados por pl.fecha**